# Vue Router params not updating in page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Hello I have some conditional logic in my view based on the current page

in setup I have

```
const curVidType = ref(route.params.videoTopic);
```

I return it and then print out like

```
<h1>Welcome to  {{ curVidType }} videos</h1>
```

However it only works if I refresh. If I browse to a new page it stays the old one even though the browser url changes. after refresh it updates. Thanks so much for any help

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `:key` to your Component to make sure it updates when param changes:

```
<your-component :key="$route.params.videoTopic"></your-component>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing the variable as a const, which means it does it once and then doesn't set it. If you change curVidType to a computed value, you can have it react to changes in the router params.

```js
computed: {
  curVidType() {
    return route.params.videoTopics
  }
}
```

This will have the value of curVidType set to change when videoTopics does

EDIT:

Having read the comments and looked at the comments and read some of the documentations, ref() will create a reactive object but I'm not sure it's reacting to the original object. But it looks like the [toRef()](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref) function can create that bridge.

```js
const curVidType = toRef(route.params, 'videoTopics')
```

Should allow for curVidType.value to also reflect changes to to route.params.videoTopics

Comment: This is not a case. Sure `computed` should help but, `ref` is returning a ProxyObject with a reactive `value` property. This property is being overridden not the whole `const`

Comment: The curVidType is reactive, but what changes the value? It gets set by the ref(route.params.videoTopic) initialization, but that means the curVidType object has a value a field that's set. route.params.videoTopic is changing, but curVidType is not.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if you could share some more code with us in order to help you.
This should just work fine

```
<template>
{{ curVidType }}
</template>

<script>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
    setup() {
        const { params } = useRoute();
        const curVidType = params.videoTopic

        return {
            curVidType,
        };
    },
};
</script>
```